How to get a total that is equal to NA and a value otherwise?
values1 <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,3)
values2 <- c(1,2,NA,4,NA,NA,2,3)
values3 <- c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA,2,3)

df<- data.frame(values1,values2,values3)

df$tot <- rowSums(df[,c('values1','values2', 'values3')], na.rm=T)
df



Rows 3 and 6 should sum to NA. If the row is comprised of all missing values then the sum should be NA. But if there is atleaset one non-missing value the non-missing values should be added up. How might I do this please?

df$tot=apply(df, 1, \(x) sum(x, na.rm=!all(is.na(x))))
df
  values1 values2 values3 tot
1       1       1       1   3
2       2       2       2   6
3      NA      NA      NA  NA
4      NA       4       4   8
5      NA      NA       5   5
6      NA      NA      NA  NA
7       2       2       2   6
8       3       3       3   9


Thank you that's amazing; so much appreciated.
